# laravel Expected response code 250 but got code "530"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Im trying to Mail in Laravel 5.1

my mail.php code is

```
 return [
     'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
     'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
     'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
     'from' => ['address' => 'myemail@gmail.com', 'name' => 'sample'],
     'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
     'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
     'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
     'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
     'pretend' => env('MAIL_PRETEND', false),

 ];
```

my .env file is

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

my function to email is

```
public function sendEmailVerification()
{
    $user = $this->user;//retrieved by $request->user() in __construct

    Mail::send('emails.verifyemail', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
        $m->from('myemail@gmail.com, 'sample');

        $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Verify Email');
    });
}
```

Error appears every time i call my function.

> Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0
> Must issue a STARTTLS command first. l188sm21749863pfl.28 - gsmtp"

Comment: if you newly edit your .env file, you need to restart your server and see if it works.

Comment: i tried that many times sir. still the same error

Comment: i stop then run php artisan serve everytime i edit my .env file

Comment: I think you need replace your  `MAIL_ENCRYPTION = null` to `MAIL_ENCRYPTION = ssl`

Comment: Check if your mail port 587 is not blocked by Windows firewall else install some third-party SMTP server.

Comment: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]
when i used sll in MAIL_ENCRYPTION

Comment: i already enable port 587 in windows firewall but still get the same error

Comment: I have answered a similar question recently. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64777498/mail-config-for-laravel-over-roundcube/64783176#64783176

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you need to enable your 2 step verification from gmail account.

https://myaccount.google.com/security

then use the generated key from there to your ENV_PASSWORD instead your real password.

Comment: how can i go to the 2 step verification page sir?

Comment: upon clicking the link. sign in your google account if not sign in.

then find the 2-Step verification then instruction will go through..

after that wizard sign your app(website) and generate your key

Comment: also, set MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls  while configuring smtp

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=<<your email address>>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<<app password>>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

Comment: Until now, we always activate allow less secure apps to send email. Didn't know we can do this.

Answer (score 56):

I had the same problem. I changed,

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null to 
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls 

php artisan config:cache
```

and it worked.

Comment: Thanks you save me a day for my production, since 2 days my emails queue was blocked in production. I forget to update encryption to `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls` in .env file. And you only need `php artisan config:cache` if you cache your config so that the codes in queue can find new config.

Comment: Good explanation. I had made changes to env file but forgot to clear cache

Comment: i am getting an same issue Expected response code "250" but got code "530", with message "530-5.7.0 Authentication Required , I have changed 
I had the same problem. I changed,

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null to 
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls  but not working for me..Can anyone help me in that?

Answer (score 10):

Use `SSL` and port `465` like this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=mail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=12345678
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

100% will work.

Answer (score 4):

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

change it to

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Just Change your encryption type to '**tls**' and it would work and make sure
your google account's `'LESS SECURE APP ACCESS'` setting is turned '**ON**' and also after changing your **.env** file **you should restart your laravel server**.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Change in `.env` file:

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Clear cache:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

For Gmail accounts you need also turn on "Less secure app access" on  https://myaccount.google.com/security. However that option shouldn't be changed on your main (personal) account.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Manage Your Google Account page then at the Security tab go to App passwords and get new random code. use it at .env file and replace it with an email password.

Answer (score 2):

I edited mail.php file like this, problem solved

```
 'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'MAIL_HOST'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 'MAIL_PORT'),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'local_domain' => env('MAIL_EHLO_DOMAIN'),
        ],
```

Answer (score 1):

change your MAIL_ENCRYPTION = null to MAIL_ENCRYPTION = ssl or MAIL_ENCRYPTION = tls. i had this issue before and changing to MAIL_ENCRYPTION = tls worked for me. also make sure that your mail settings in config\mail.php is the same as .env file

Answer (score 1):

After enabling logging to the mail from the less secured devices, make sure that `.env` file contains the following configurations:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=your_email@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD="your_passwrod_here"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Make sure that your password is rounded by the double quotes `""`.

Make sure that your `mail.php` file contains configurations like the following:

```
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'your_email@gmail.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'your_email'),
],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
```

And don't forget to close the server and run `php artisan config:clear` to clear the configuration cache.

This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You should restart the artisan after those changes. That was the issue for me.