# How to fix error Swift_TransportException in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel-5, smtp, gmail

working with laravel 5.6 and I am going to send contact form details via the gmail. My .env file is look like this,

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myname@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

but when I send submit buttons following error is coming,

```
1/1) Swift_TransportException

Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. u21-v6sm32263983pfa.176 - gsmtp
"
in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383
```

how can fix this project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel Expected response code 250 but got code "530"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574375/laravel-expected-response-code-250-but-got-code-530)

Answer (score 0):

I guess I have faced this issue when I had wrong `password` in `.env` for given email id