# View [email.wellcome] Not Found in Laravel Mail

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-mail

I can't send mail using Laravel. At first, I set all details for Mail in `.env`.

**Controller**

```php
$value = "myemail@example.com";
\Mail::to($value)->send(new welcome);

return redirect('/smsverify');
```

**Here's my mail code:**

```php
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class wellcome extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('email.wellcome');
    }
}
```

I don't understand why I see `View [email.wellcome] not found.` I already cleared my Laravel cache but that's not solved!

Comment: change to email.welcome maybe your view name is welcome

Comment: i created a folder name of `email` ,then creat in `wellcome.blade.php`

Comment: Try return view('email.wellcome');

Comment: $this->view is not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check in your `views/email` folder exist `welcome.blade.php` file

Comment: but i see `Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. n73sm111615093pfj.148 - gsmtp "`

Comment: @Nirab: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574375/laravel-expected-response-code-250-but-got-code-530) will be helpful for you

Comment: @Nirab: Yes you can send mail using local server

Comment: @Nirab: Please accept my answer if it's work for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186356/discussion-between-saurabh-dhariwal-and-nirab).