# how to send an email in my api function with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, email

so this is an exemple of fonction : I create an event and depending on the situation I want to send an email to the person with a message

[image]

I want to send the mail back-end without any view given that it is notification mail can i do that in laravel ?

do not hesitate to ask for more information/code

Comment: Have you tried Laravel markdown mails?

Comment: put here code instead of image, please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139931/laravel-mail-pass-string-instead-of-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `Mail::raw`, so your message (i mean text) should be first argument. And you have to pass `@email` via `use`:

```php
$msg = 'Un evement...';
Mail::raw($msg, function ($message) use ($email) {
    $message->to($email);
    $message->subject('Planning');
});
```

Comment: i had this error "message": "Class 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\Mail' not found" 
i don't know how to configure that 
do I need a controller ?

Comment: add in `use` section `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;`

Comment: ok now i had this error "message": "Expected response code 250 but got code \"530\", with message \"530 5.7.1 Authentication required\r\n\"",

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574375/laravel-expected-response-code-250-but-got-code-530