# Expected response code 250 but got code "530"

Tags: laravel

Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command

`first. q3sm42480784wrn.33 - gsmtp`

"

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME='my@gmail.com'
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypass
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: Do you have 2FA set up on the account?

Comment: no i don't have

Comment: Going from the error the first thing I would try is to change the encryption to `MAIL_ENCRYPTION= STARTTLS`. Also, you don't need the quotes around this email address.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laravel Expected response code 250 but got code "530"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574375/laravel-expected-response-code-250-but-got-code-530)