# Laravel 6- Mail not sending from localhost

Tags: laravel

It showing me this error

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with the message "530-5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError
```

while I have enabled two-factor authentication and generated an app password.

**here is my `.env`**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=myAppGeneratedPassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

**and here is my mail.php**

```php
<?php

return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'myemail@gmail.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'my_name'),
    ],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('myemail@gmail.com'),
    'password' => env('appPassword'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,
    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',
        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/mail'),
        ],
    ],
];
```

Please help me. I am trying for three days.

Comment: Try with ssl. That's work for me on localhost

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laravel Expected response code 250 but got code "530"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574375/laravel-expected-response-code-250-but-got-code-530)

Comment: not working for me...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this config

```
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Comment: maybe, when sending email with laravel need real server and inlcuding ssl not from localhost