# Mail config for Laravel over RoundCube

Tags: laravel, email, ovh, laravel-mail

I am using Laravel to send out some emails from RoundCube. The trouble is that I keep getting the same error

```
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "user@email.com" using 2 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated
 ". Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated.
```

I have looked around and havent found an accurate answer for that. Here is a part of the **.env** file that is relevant to the problem at hand.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=ssl0.ovh.net
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=user@email.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=somepassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

I tried to replace the `MAIL_ENCRYPTION` and `MAIL_PORT` with `tls` and `587` respectively. Also, I made sure that the credentials actually work. I also looked at the ovh docs which were not helpful at all for sending mails. Also, there is no option to allow less secure accounts like in Gmail.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a hosting account from OVH that includes an MX plan? This is necessary. Also try `smtp.mail.ovh.ca` instead.

Answer (score -1):

First remove all mail configuration from .env file stated with MAIL_

Then open your mail.php from config folder and create a new array under smtp.

```
'gmail' => [
        'transport' => 'smtp',
        'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'encryption' => 'ssl',
        'username' => 'aravvi@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'xxigefvqehfypdmg',
    ],
```

then mention it in your default mailer

```
'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'gmail'),
```

run these commnands

```
php artisan config:clear
```

and

```
compser dump-autoload
```

then

```
php artisan serve
```

hope will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Hassan, I did try your suggestion and used the settings of OVH, but Im still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you please share your current system config, laravel installation config and your mail.php config